# protobuf.js Runtime Error $protobuf is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, protocol-buffers

I am using protobuf.js in an ionic2 project.  I have a valid .proto file which I first convert to a static javascript file by:

```
pbjs -t static databaseapi.proto > databaseapi.js
```

Becasue ionic2 uses typescript, I add a d.ts file by doing:

```
pbts databaseapi.js > databaseapi.d.ts
```

my application transpiles and runs, but I end up with a runtime error:

**Runtime Error $protobuf is not defined**

I know it is because the compiled protocol buffer file references the variable $protobuf, but I don't quite know where this variable is defined.  I also don't know how to include the missing file because it needs to be referenced by the js file rather than the ts file.

Comment: That's the issue with generated code :-/ Guess you have to consult the ProtoBuf documentation. My uninformed guess is that you need to also include the protobuf lib.

Comment: Yeah, I tried `import * as $protobuf from "protobufjs";` in both the page controller and app.module.ts to no avail.

Comment: Did you try this: https://github.com/dcodeIO/protobuf.js#usage-with-typescript The import is different in the browser for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks dcode, I ended up doing it a little differently.  To others reading this, the solution is Ionic specific, please see the answer by dcode for a better generic solution.

What I ended up doing, was adding a reference to the compiled js file to Cordova's index.html as follows:

```
<script src="lib/protobuf.js"></script>
<script>$protobuf = protobuf;</script>
<script src="js/databaseapi.js"></script>
<script> $database = $root.com.database.api.v1; </script>
```

databaseapi.js is the name of the compiled protobuf file.

Comment: Right, you can do that in a global context. This will, however, pollute it somewhat with an additional $Reader, $Writer, $util and a $root variable and will not assure strict mode is on.

Comment: Just added a "closure" wrapper that avoids any possible issues. Usage: `pbjs -t static-module -w closure -r databaseapi databaseapi.proto`. This generates a JS file that, where `protobuf` is a global, adds everything to `protobuf.roots.databaseapi` (that's what the -r switch is for). Doesn't pollute and ensures strict mode.

Answer (score 5):

`-t static` just creates the raw code but doesn't wrap it as a module (and thus does not define the `$protobuf` dependency).

To also wrap it as a module, use `-t static-module` and pick your desired format through `-w default|commonjs|amd|es6`. `default` uses an universal wrapper that works with AMD, CommonJS and a global variable.

For all command line options, see: https://github.com/dcodeIO/protobuf.js#command-line